# pandas Series from all possible combination of certain column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this

```
  method   method_par1   variantB_option   x   y
0     m1    variantA             NaN       2  13
1     m1    variantA             NaN       1  11
2     m2         NaN             NaN       1   7
3     m2         NaN             NaN       5   3
4     m1    variantB              25      10   9
5     m1    variantB              25       5   3
6     m1    variantB              15      54  39
7     m1    variantB              15       1   4
```

and I would like to extrapolate various Series from this, to plot the values of column 'y' against 'x'. Each of this Series should have one of the unique combinations of values from the first 3 columns (disregarding the Index).

So I would like to have the following DataFrames

```
df1
  method   method_par1   variantB_option   x   y
0     m1    variantA             NaN       2  13
1     m1    variantA             NaN       1  11



df2
  method   method_par1   variantB_option   x   y
2     m2         NaN             NaN       1   7
3     m2         NaN             NaN       5   3


df3
  method   method_par1   variantB_option   x   y

4     m1    variantB              25      10   9
5     m1    variantB              25       5   3


df4  
  method   method_par1   variantB_option   x   y
6     m1    variantB              15      54  39
7     m1    variantB              15       1   4
```

The possible values of each of the first columns are all finite, so there is a limited (but big) number of possibilities.

I can of course do this by using nested `for` loops and concatenating stuff like `df[df['method'] == 'm1']`, but in my real (larger) example it gets really messy and I was wondering if there is a more clean way. Maybe using something like `groupby`?

Comment: you want every 2 rows? or any N number of samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and iterate it over:

```
dfs = [v for k, v in df.groupby(['method', 'method_par1', 'variantB_option'])['x', 'y']]
dfs[0]
  method method_par1 variantB_option  x   y
0     m1    variantA             NaN  2  13
1     m1    variantA             NaN  1  11
dfs[1]
  method method_par1 variantB_option   x   y
6     m1    variantB              15  54  39
7     m1    variantB              15   1   4
dfs[2]
  method method_par1 variantB_option   x  y
4     m1    variantB              25  10  9
5     m1    variantB              25   5  3
dfs[3]
  method method_par1 variantB_option  x  y
2     m2         NaN             NaN  1  7
3     m2         NaN             NaN  5  3
```

If your `NaN` is a real *Not a Number*, `groupby` will only return the triplets without `NaN`. In such case, use `df.fillna()` with your preference of value.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to `fillna`

```
for x , y in df.fillna('NaN').groupby(['method','method_par1','variantB_option']):
    print(y)

  method method_par1 variantB_option  x   y
0     m1    variantA             NaN  2  13
1     m1    variantA             NaN  1  11
  method method_par1 variantB_option   x   y
6     m1    variantB              15  54  39
7     m1    variantB              15   1   4
  method method_par1 variantB_option   x  y
4     m1    variantB              25  10  9
5     m1    variantB              25   5  3
  method method_par1 variantB_option  x  y
2     m2         NaN             NaN  1  7
3     m2         NaN             NaN  5  3

d={ x:y.replace({'NaN':np.nan})   for x , y in df.fillna('NaN').groupby(['method','method_par1','variantB_option'])
```